# erro ao utilizar o db:migrate do sequelize "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, terminal, sequelize-js

Estou utilizando o sequelize para fazer a comunicação com o banco de dados, mas ao utilizar o comando: **npx sequelize-cli db:migrate** aparece o seguinte erro **getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1:3007**, alguém tem ideia do que possa ser?

Em anexo está a config.json dele + o erro que apareceu no terminal, desde já agradeço a ajuda, se for necessário enviar mais alguma parte do código para que tenham uma ideia melhor podem falar.

```
"development": {
"username": "root",
"password": "admin123",
"database": "E-commerce",
"host": "127.0.0.1:3307",
"dialect": "mysql"},
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pela descrição do erro, parece que o servidor de banco de dados não está no ar. Precisa verificar se você consegue conexão por fora do sequelize usando o endereço, porta e credenciais que você está tentando utilizar.  O que me chamou a atenção foi a porta (3307), por padrão o MySQL usa 3306

Comment: @Bins Quando eu crio uma conexão pela porta 3306 aparece isso: 14:05:56 Could not connect, server may not be running. Unable to connect to localhost, o que pode ser?